# How to interpret and quantify coefficients of slope and intercept in segmented regression

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I'm fitting a segmented (piecewise) linear regression on time-series data with break points representing an intervention. My goal is to assess wether the intervention significantly changed the trend (slope) of the the regression line. [Here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic79832.files/L06_Program_Evaluation_2/Segmented_Regression.Wagner.2002.pdf) is a description of the method I'm trying to employ. The paper explains in fairly simple terms the theory behind how this can be accomplished. I just can't seem to wrap my head around what this would look like in R code. Consider the following.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
      value = sample(seq(from = 40, to = 50, by = 1), size = 50, replace = TRUE),
      time = 1:50, 
      intervention1 = ifelse(time >= 25, 1, 0), 
      intervention2 = ifelse(time >= 35, 1, 0)
)
fit <- lm(value ~ time + intervention1*time + intervention2*time, data = df)
```

In this example, would the coefficients `intervention1` and `intervention2` represent the possible change in intercept estimated to occur due to each respective intervention? And would the interaction terms `intervention1:timeTRUE` and `intervention2:timeTRUE` represent the possible change in slope owing to the interventions?

Comment: Look again at page 6 of the article linked, your data setup seems to be flawed. For an beginner-level examplel on segmented/piecewise regression with R see https://climateecology.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/r-for-ecologists-putting-together-a-piecewise-regression/

Comment: @majom thank you for your input. I will review the linked article again and your linked website. I had a feeling I was fundamentally misunderstanding something and this is why I asked.